# O que é um context no Android?

Tags: android, android-context

O que é um `context` no Android?

Qual a diferença entre `getContext()`, `getApplicationContext()`, `getBaseContext()`?

Tem alguma relação com getActivity?

Comment: Segundo a [Square](http://corner.squareup.com/2014/10/advocating-against-android-fragments.html) o `Context` é um [god object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object), e `Activity` é um `Context` que vem com um ciclo de vida. ;)

Comment: Pode por uma resposta mais precisa? Para eu aceitar

Answer (score 45, accepted):

*(Referências: documentação oficial e [duas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9606712/2241463) [perguntas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10641144/difference-between-getcontext-getapplicationcontext-getbasecontext-and) do SOen.)*

### Context

> É um ponto de acesso para informações globais sobre um
>   ambiente de aplicativo. Trata-se de uma classe abstrata cuja
>   implementação é fornecida pelo sistema Android. Ela permite acesso a
>   recursos e classes específicas de aplicativo, bem como chamadas para
>   operações em nível de aplicativo como iniciar
>   *activities*, enviar ou receber *intents* por *broadcast*, etc.

Em outras palavras, `Context` é a maneira fornecida pelo sistema para seu aplicativo acessar determinados recursos (como o recurso de iniciar uma *activity*, iniciar ou parar um *service*, enviar um *broadcast*, abrir um banco de dados ou arquivo de preferências, etc.) ou classes (como os diversos `Managers` que o sistema oferece: gerenciador de Telefonia, de Alarme, de Sensores, de Áudio, de Notificações, de Energia, de USB, etc). Esses recursos e classes têm a particularidade de serem globais no nível do aplicativo, isto é, são de nível de aplicativo. Não deixa de ser um [god object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object) como diz a [Square](http://corner.squareup.com/2014/10/advocating-against-android-fragments.html) - e, de fato, sem uma instância de `Context` você não faz muita coisa em um aplicativo Android.

### Application

> Classe-base para aqueles que precisam preservar estado global de aplicativo.
>   Você pode fornecer sua própria implementação (normalmente não há
>   necessidade, e singletons estáticos podem fornecer a mesma
>   funcionalidade de uma maneira mais modular).

### Activity

> Uma activity é uma coisa única e focada que o usuário pode fazer.

### Service

> É um componente de aplicativo que pode tanto representar o desejo de um aplicativo de executar um operação de maior duração ao mesmo tempo em que evita interagir com o usuário ou fornecer funcionalidades para outros aplicativos usarem.

`Application`, `Activity` e `Service` são concretizações de `Context`, isto é, classes concretas que implementam um `Context` do Android. Quando você estende essas classes em seu código, você tem acesso aos serviços de nível de aplicativo fornecidos pelo `Context` herdado por essas classes. Além disso, tem acesso a recursos específicos de cada subclasse; por exemplo, a `Activity` ativa no momento pode ser fechada através do método `finish()` e pode executar código no thread principal de maneira simples através do método `runOnUiThread()`. `Activities`, `Services` e `Applications` têm cada um o seu ciclo de vida particular. E nem sempre os contextos são intercambiáveis; por exemplo, se você tentar exibir um `Dialog` passando para ele um contexto `Application`, isto causará um erro devido ao Android esperar que seja passada uma `Activity` (este problema em especial se trata mais de uma idiossincrasia do Android, que deveria esperar receber logo uma `Activity`).

### Diferenças entre os métodos

- `View.getContext()`: Retorna o contexto no qual a view está sendo exibida. Geralmente a `Activity` ativa no momento.
- `Activity.getApplicationContext()`: Retorna o contexto do aplicativo inteiro (o processo dentro do qual todas as Activities estão sendo executadas). Use este no lugar do contexto da Activity ativa no momento se você estiver precisando de um contexto vinculado ao ciclo de vida do aplicativo inteiro.
- `ContextWrapper.getBaseContext()`: É um método da classe `ContextWrapper`. E `ContextWrapper` é "uma implementação *proxy* de `Context` que simplesmente delega todas as suas chamadas para um outro `Context`. Pode ser estendida para modificar comportamentos sem alterar o `Context` original."
- `Fragment.getActivity()`: Retorna a `Activity` à qual está anexado este fragmento. Um fragmento não possui `Context` por si só; porém, quando se encontra ligado (*attached* ou *added*) a uma `Activity` tem acesso ao contexto dessa `Activity`, ou então se guarda uma instância de `Application` tem acesso a essa instância mesmo estando desligado da `Activity`.

Comment: Ótima resposta.

Answer (score 4):

Como o nome sugere, é o contexto do objeto ou aplicação. É uma forma de acessar no código o estado atual da aplicação.

No Android, `Context` é a classe base para `Activity`, `Service`, `Application`, portanto, é uma forma de acessar e lidar com a sua aplicação via código.