# Como chamar um alertDialog dentro de um fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragment

Não consigo chamar um alertDialog dentro de um fragment. No momento de definir o builder(this) ele retorna erro. Segue código:

```
public void mostrarMsg(String titulo, String mensagem) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setCancelable(true);
    builder.setTitle(titulo);
    builder.setMessage(mensagem);
    builder.show();
}
```

Este código funciona normalmente dentro de uma activity quando é chamado, mas quando é colocado dentro de um fragment retorna erro no 'this'. Qual é a razão e como pode ser solucionado?

Comment: Coloca o GetActivity() que vai servir para isso, ele vai retornar a activity que o fragment esta contido.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Troque o `this` por `getActivity()` que vai resolver seu problema.

A razão disso é que ele espera que você passe um `Context` ali dentro, uma `Activity` é um `Context`, pois ela estende da classe `Context`, então quando você utiliza o `this` você está se referindo ao objeto atual, no caso seu `Fragment` não é um `Context`.

---

**Veja mais sobre context aqui:**

[O que é um context no Android?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/38853/o-que-%C3%A9-um-context-no-android)

Comment: Certo, mas como vou chamar este método que está dentro da fragment através de um button que está dentro da mesma? É possível fazer isso pelo java apenas?

Comment: Não entendi, na pergunta você disse que não estava funcionando este código em um `Fragment` e estava apresentado erro no `this`. Para isto basta apenas substituir o `this` por `getActivity()` para obter o `context`da activity.

Comment: Sim... consegui fazer isto.. Agora minha intenção é chamar este método atraves de um button que está no xml do fragment. Agora na verdade a dúvida seria outra rs. Como que posso então, já que consegui criar este método dentro do fragment, coloca-lo no onclick de um button que está dentro da fragment entendeu? Gostaria de fazer isto pelo java e não pelo XML.

Comment: Como é um contexto totalmente diferente da sua pergunta, seria interessante você criar uma nova com essa dúvida do clique, pois não existe nenhuma atualmente no site.

Comment: Ok muito obrigado.