# Context, quando usar?

Tags: android

Minha pergunta é simples , qual a função do context em uma aplicação ?
qual a diferença entre usar um e não usar?

obrigado desde já !

Comment: Em que contexto se está a referir a Context? Não entendo quando pergunta: "qual a diferença entre usar um e não usar?"

Comment: Queria saber porque utilizar context em um app , nao entendo nada sobre context

Comment: Tente reformular a sua pergunta. Você se refere à classe Context? Se sim, não há a questão de "usar ou não usar", é obrigatório usar quando tal é necessário.

Comment: Então mais eu queria saber quando é necessário kk

Comment: Veja se é isto o que procura: [O que é um context no Android?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/38853/2541).

Comment: Ou isto [Qual diferença entre os métodos para obter um contexto?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/180349/2541)

Comment: Isso mesmo , obrigado