# Como criar método de envio de mensagem em Tabs?

Tags: android

Estou criando um app, em android, que possui tabs. Cada tab é uma sala de chat. Peguei um exemplo de um vídeo sobre como criar app com Tabs, onde o autor, além de criar o app usando um modelo de tabs, ele criar uma classe tab para cada uma das tabs e um xml para cada um delas também. Conclui que para enviar uma mensagem, em uma determinada tab, eu teria que criar o método de envio de mensagem na classe tab, de cada uma delas, porém, não estou conseguindo fazer a devida "ligação" do campo de texto (TextView) nessa classe, pois o comando findoViewById() não aparece na classe tab!

```
package com.example.gustavo.vigilantescomunitarios;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class TabRua extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_rua, container, false);


    }

}
```

Comment: Tentou usar a classe [Context](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/38853/o-que-%C3%A9-um-context-no-android)?

Comment: Desculpe, mas como assim?

Comment: Dá uma olhada nesse [tópico](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6495898/findviewbyid-in-fragment) e veja se te ajuda.

Comment: Não entendi, muito bem o que tem que ser feito kkkkk desculpa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você não cosnegue usar o `findviewById` porque você não está usando a root inflada do layout, quando você extende a um fragment as coisas são um pouco diferentes de quando você extende a uma Activity, você tem que acessar os outros layouts através do layout inflado:

```
public class TabRua extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_rua, container, false);
    Textview textView = rootView.findviewById(R.id.textView); //Apenas um exemplo
    return rootView;
}
```

Comment: Agora estou tentando criar o método para enviar a mensagem e colocando uma Toast, mas o método tem como parâmetro (View view). Preciso pegar a mensagem digitada na textview

Comment: Hunmm você pode fazer de várias formas essa transação, da uma lida na arquitetura MVP talvez lhe ajude

Comment: Onde encontro essa arquitetura MVP? Na documentação do android?

Comment: Onde vejo isso @Matheus?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar a classe `Bundle` e passar uma instancia dessa classe para o seu `Fragment`no ato da sua `Intent`.

Exemplo:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("foo", "bar"); // chave e valor, respectivamente
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

E para pegar os dados no seu `Fragment`

```
Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();

if (bundle != null) {
    String foo = bundle.getInt("foo", "VALOR_PADRAO");
}
```

EDIT 1: Quanto ao `findViewById()`, recomendo você dar uma olhada na biblioteca [ButterKnife](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife) para lidar com *view binding*.

Comment: Cara sobre o Bundle eu sei, a questão é outra.

Comment: A sua pergunta é pouco explicativa. Você quer trocar mensagem de um `TextView` de uma tab para um `TextView` de outra tab?

Comment: Não, vc quem não entendeu... Cada Tab é um canal de chat e cada TextView manda mensagem para seu respectivo canal! É um chat normal!

Comment: Você quer fazer a ligação do seu `TextView `? Tente isso: `TextView textView = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.text_view);`